# Is there a formula or pattern for how many triangles N lines can define?

Tags: geometry

While i was bored I came uo with this question and I just have to know
Is there a formula or pattern for how many triangles N lines can define?
for example:If N=3 then the maximum of triangles that can be defined is three
What im asking is if theres a formula or pattern that dictates whats the maximum of triangles when the value of N is something else

Comment: How do you construct three triangles from three lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you meant a couple of things (maybe I'm wrong):

- By *line* you mean *line segment* (a finite length line).
- *Line segments* are only allowed to intersect at their end points.

In which case I don't have a rigourous proof, but I suspect that this is the optimal layout for more than $2$ triangles ($T = 2$):

[image]

Leading to $N$ being at least $2T$, and so $T$ is at most $\lfloor N/2 \rfloor$ ($N$ divided by $2$ and rounded down).

Comment: Ah perfect.I actually didnt know what i was looking for between the two.So many thanks for both answers

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is such a formula. However, your opening statement is wrong: if $N=3$, at most *one* triangle can be formed.

HINT: any triangle is determined by three lines, and three lines determine at most one triangle . . .

> Given $n$ lines, the number of triangles they form is at most $\binom n3$.

Comment: Ok I know that.But lets say N=5 that would give me two triangles using one of the other triangles lines to define it.So I dont quite understand your "hint". Could you develop a bit more?

Comment: @VictorGonzalez I don't understand your computation. If you have five lines - $A, B, C, D, E$ - then you can form many more than 2 triangles. E.g. (assuming no two are parallel and no three intersect at a point - this is called "general position") we have ABC, BCD, CDE, and several others. Do you see why?

Comment: Im sorry if I sound dumb.Im not well versed in maths but with a big interest in it.you told me if N=3 then one can define at most one triangle but from practice i can see that if N=4 is 2 triangles and N=5 is 4.Exactly how can I be sure those are the maximum ammount of triangles I can make.I'm sorry but I dont quite understand you.

Comment: sorry forgot to put that in my comment

Comment: @VictorGonzalez I don't know why you think you can only make two triangles with four lines. HINT: Draw three lines forming a triangle (NOTE: extend them beyond the triangle - lines go off to infinity!), and then draw one new line that intersects each of the three lines you've already drawn, and *doesn't* intersect two of them at once. You'll now be able to draw four distinct triangles.

Comment: Oh do'h silly me.Thanks for dummying it down

Comment: @NoahSchweber - I suspect that by "line" the OP means line segments.

Comment: @Myridium Then extend them far enough. It still works.

Comment: @NoahSchweber - Right. I had assumed that the OP was treating a line cut by another as being split into two segments (i.e. intersections allowed only at segment end points), but I could be very wrong.